# Android MotionEvent ACTION_MOVE efficiency. How to improve performance?

Tags: android, performance, touch-event

I am currently working on an app that allows for free-drawing.

The current method I am using is as follows:

currentLine is a list that keeps a history of all points that `ACTION_MOVE` returns.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Point p = new Point(event.getX(),event.getY());
                currentLine.addPoint(p);
                    invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;

}
```

I then take these points and draw them in the `onDraw` method of my class.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);

    //Draw Background Color
    c.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

    //Setup Paint
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    p.setColor(COLOR.WHITE);

    //iterate through points
    if(currentLine.size()>0){
        for(int x = 0;x<currentLine.size();x++){
            c.drawCircle(currentLine.get(x).getX(), currentLine.get(x).getY(), 3, p);
        }
    }

}
```

And this method works great, with no lag or anything.

Except, it does not get *enough* of the points that it needs to.

For example, if I am to drag my finger quickly across the entire screen, it may only draw 15 points of the whole event.

How can I improve the performance/speed of the MotionEvent? How can I get *more* points? Or is there something else I should be doing?

**----EDIT----**

I have managed to solve it myself.

Instead of using `drawCircle`, I switched to `drawLine`.

Example:

```
if(points.size()>0){
        for(int x = 0;x<points.size()-1;x++){
            c.drawLine(points.get(x).getX(), points.get(x).getY(), points.get(x+1).getX(), points.get(x+1).getY(), p);
        }
}
```

This produces solid lines, which is what I wanted.

**However, for the sake of knowledge, I would still like to know how to speed up MotionEvents.**

***A detailed answer would be appreciated***

Comment: I found that if I kept "drawing" after a short while, the number of events increased dramatically. It was almost as though Android noticed that this app was doing what it was doing and allocated more resources to it. I'm very curious if anyone offers a useful answer here.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I have updated my thread with a possible work-around, maybe it can help you.

Comment: no no, I was using solid lines as well, but I'm hoping someone chimes in with a way to force a more rapid even firing.

Comment: Yes, that would really end up helping me as well.

Comment: Are you using a extension of a SurfaceView, or a regular View?

Comment: A regular View, but that is exchangeable if needed.

Comment: @MrZander: If you would move your drawing to another thread (using surfaceview is a good way to do this), it would not be able to block the motionevents, which would be able to fire more often. Otherwise you have to wait for the drawing to complete before you can get a new motion.
(Sorry for the late answer, I didn't get notified that you had answered on my question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bottleneck is the drawing method, obviously.

If you are working on android 3.0+, draw all those crazy things on the GPU.
Add the attribute

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

to the `<application>` tag in your manifest. This will unbelievably increase drawing time.

Additionally, try to not redraw the whole thing if only a little needs to be updated.
Invoke invalidate(Rect dirty) instead of invalidate().

Comment: I am working with Android 2.2, but I will look into invalidate(Rect dirty).  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You should also get more points by utilizing event.getHistoricalX/Y() functions

Comment: More information on how to implement this would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html and the section "Batching".

Comment: I think this is the most useful approach, actually

Answer (score 0):

Put a small thread sleep in the motion event; that helped me solve the problem when a ton of movement events were jamming the listener.

```
Thread.sleep(100);
```

Comment: I *want* more events. How will sleeping help this?

Answer (score 0):

invalidate(); is harmful for performance. Try to calculate bounds rect and call invalidate(bounds)