# How to get length of screen dragged?

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oodxJ.png)i have 2 similar picture in the similar position that one of them is blur and another is not .
i want to remove specific area of the blur one with finger touch like[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oodxJ.png)

i use `touchEventlistener` but have problem when i drag fast ,`tocuhevent`does not record all of points

public class CustomView extends View  {

```
private Bitmap destBitmap;
private Canvas destCanvas;
private Paint destPaint;
private Path destPath;


public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    destCanvas = new Canvas();
    destPaint = new Paint();
    destPath = new Path();

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)    context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    destBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    destCanvas.setBitmap(destBitmap);
    destCanvas.drawBitmap(blurImage(), 0, 0, null);


    destPaint.setAlpha(0);
    destPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    destPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    destPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    destPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    destPaint.setStrokeWidth(50);
     destPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));



}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (pixels < 6) {
        destCanvas.drawPath(destPath, destPaint);

    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(destBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int xPos = (int)event.getX();
    final int yPos = (int)event.getY();

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // if user has released finger
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            destPath.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            destPath.lineTo(xPos, yPos);

            break;
        default:
            return false;

    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public Bitmap blurImage() {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.image);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,1080,1794,false);



    return outputBitmap;

}

int pixels=0;

}
```

i need to create something like this

[image]

Comment: see if this helps https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-create-a-paint-application-for-android-5b16968063f8

Comment: I think the issue is onDraw() method. It takes some time to run your code. So when it is running the UI blocks and at that time all time no touch events are registered because the UI is halted. That is why when you drag fast not all the points are registered. Try making use of hardware acceleration. Maybe this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484545/android-motionevent-action-move-efficiency-how-to-improve-performance.

Comment: Also try watching Android Performance Patterns videos on custom views and performance, the relation between UI and GPU and a Rendering tool to detect what is causing your UI to halt. Here are all the links you should watch. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK2i7ivzK7M&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=50&t=0s. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzYkVL1n4M8 . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WH9AFhgwmDw